# Is there a way to change the pitch of audio being played in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day. Is there a way for me to use a plugin to change the pitch of a sound being played through the flutter application?

Comment: What have you tried to get it to change pitch? What is creating the sound in flutter?

Comment: Insert a resampler between the audio source and the sound card, but leave the sound card frequency the same. So, for example, you have a recording at 44.1 kHz: resample that to 46.7 kHz, but leave the sound card set to 44.1. Pitch changed by a semitone.

Comment: @returnVoid What's creating the sound in Flutter is a audio file in the assets folder.

Comment: Any update on this? I need something similar

Comment: Kingdom or Jonas did any of you ever figure out a solution that works for you?

Comment: I also need a solution here!

Comment: Nothing yet,just changed the pitch of the audio files manually. Don't think there's a library for flutter that can do that.

Comment: Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ogg_piano

Answer (score 1):

I see there is still no answer.

You can use setPitch method from just_audio package like this:

```
await audioPlayer.setPitch(1.5);
```

link to package: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio