# General approach to visualize audio file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, architecture, audio-player

What is the general programming approach to visualize audio file like this:

[image]

(in the middle is the current player position)

By googling I've found it could have something to do with pitch and in [Is there a way to change the pitch of audio being played in a flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717561/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-pitch-of-audio-being-played-in-a-flutter-app) I've found it could have something to do with sample rate. I'm not a musitian, but I feel the way to achieve this could be to get internal audio pitch or volume for every second.

So if some of these is correct, what could be the general programming approach to get pitch, sample rate, or internal volume for every second of an audio file?

(if you are unfamiliar with Dart, you can use any language you know, I can translate between programming languages quite well: Python, Java, JavaScript, PHP...)

(is there a way to use ffmpeg for this?)

Comment: have a look on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE7Vtzq52xg

Comment: He creates a dynamic visualizer, what I want is a static visualizer (visualize at the beginning and stay the same for the whole track)

Comment: @aleskva Did you found any solution?

Comment: @WebMaster Hi, no, not yet. My workaround is to take up to 20 characters from the audio file name or song title, convert them to numerical value and use them to visualize audio file like this: https://ctrlv.link/MRfP (I can't -> I C A N T -> ASCII 73 67 65 78 84 -> height of bars/hills/slope). Still looking for some good way to show the actual song heights/pitch/volume/kbps/whatever else defining the audio itself, not its title.

Comment: I found these links for visualizing audio: [Just audio](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/97) [Audio record view](https://dev.to/armen101/audiorecordview-3jn5) [Flutter visualizers - deprecated](https://github.com/iamSahdeep/FlutterVisualizers)
They don't provide full answer, but they are can be used as a part of the solution.